# Rails Controller testing: Does database state change persist after success of test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, controller, persistence

I am testing create method of BranchController using ActionController::TestCase (code below) . I check if object is created by calling find_by_name method(assume name is unique here). 
test runs succesfully but when i check same record in mysql db, its not there.

```
    class Security::BranchControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      test "the create" do
     post(:create, :branch => {:name => "test branch", :details=> "test branch details"})

     #replace find with where searching with all of fields 
     assert_not_nil Company::Branch.find_by_name("test branch") 
      end   
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a database that supports transactions (as most do these days), rails tests will by default set a savepoint before running each test and do a rollback at the end.

This means that the insertion is actually happening, but the result is not visible outside the test.

You should see the savepoint and rollback operations in your test logs.

If you want to disable this, you can add

> self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

in your test class, or patch it in for all your tests by adding something like

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

in your test_helper class.

It's likely not a good idea to disable this generally though, as it's a nice way to keep your tests independent.